# list slicing without using the slice function

Tags: python, list, slice

> Python provides slicing functionality for lists, but for this
>   question, you will implement your own function capable of producing
>   list slices (note: you cannot use the slicing operator in your
>   solution). The function should be called `slice` and take the following
>   three inputs in this specific order:
>
> 1. A list, `source`, which the slice will be created from. This list cannot be modified by your function.
> 2. A positive integer, `start`, representing the starting index of the slice you will create. If this value is not in the range `[0, len(list)-1]`, your function should return an empty list.
> 3. A positive integer, `end`, representing the ending index of the slice you will create. If this value is not in the range `[start, len(list)-1]`, your function should return an empty list.
>
> If the
>   parameter values are acceptable, your function will return a list that
>   contains the items from `source` beginning at the index `start` and ending
>   at the index `end` (inclusive). This is different from the Python slice
>   operator, as the item at the index `end` is also included in the new
>   list.

**This is what I got so far:**

```
    list1 = []
def slice(list1):
    list1 = list(input("enter a list"))
    emptylist = []
    st = int(input("enter start"))

    ed = int(input("enter end"))


    if ed not in range(st,len(list1)-1) or st not in range(0,len(list1)-1):
        print(emptylist)
    else:
        list2 = []

        for i in list1:
            list2.append(list1[i])
            return(list2)

print(slice(list1))
```

Comment: Your homework instructions say nothing about taking a user input. Or at least, I'm fairly certain your funciton should take these as *arguments*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the list has to be taken from the user and it can't be manipulated or changed by the function. 1-A list, source, which the slice will be created from. This list cannot be modified by your function.

Comment: Your solution looks ok to me. Did you try to run it ? To add on what juanpa said, the function should not ask for parameters. It should be this way: `def slice(List, start, end):` this way it should be declared.

Comment: Again, I'm fairly certain your instructions are implying the function should take these values as *arguments*.

Comment: Your slice only takes one argument

Comment: For the third and last time: regardless of whether you get start and end ultimately from the user, I'm **pretty certain they are suppose to be arguments to your slice function**.

Comment: Side-note: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Using tests for `someint in range(...)` on Python 2 is going to behave poorly for longish `list`s (it's going to create a huge `list` of `int`s, then scan it element by element to find a matching element). On modern Python 3, it's still slightly wasteful, but it's fixed wastefulness (the work is `O(1)`, just with a larger constant factor). You could achieve portable low overhead tests replacing code like `ed not in range(st,len(list1)-1)` with `not (st <= ed < len(list1) - 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the list input is supposed to be delimited, so I'm not going to include it in my answer. In fact, I'm just going to assume that we have somehow received a list of proper format from the user and only need to call the function on that list.

Your function would take 3 parameters, `start`, `end`, and the `list` itself because these are bare minimum requirement for a slicing task.

```
def slice(lst, start, end):
```

The simplest solution would be to iterate through the loop and add all the elements within the `start:end` range. After all, you are allowed to use indexing notation.

You would first have to create an empty list that will contain only the appropriate elements. We'll call this list an `output` list.

```
output = []
```

Then, we can iterate through all the integers between `start` and `end` because list indices are integers.

```
for i in range(start, end):
    output.append(lst[i])
```

At the end of the function, you would want to return the `output` list so you end up with an actually sliced list object.

```
return output
```

Putting it all together:

```
# some shebangs here
'''
Some docstring here
'''
# some imports here

# receive user input. You need a list and two integers.
# lst = input()
# start = input()
# end = input()

def slice(lst, start, end):
    output = []
    if not(0 <= start < len(lst)):
        return output
    elif not(start <= end < len(lst)):
        return output
    else:
        for i in range(start, end+1):
            output.append(lst[i])
        return output

print(slice(lst, start, end))
```

## **Why doesn't your original script work?**

Issue with your code is in the last line. If you do:

```
for i in list1:
    list2.append(list1[i])
    return(list2)
```

First of all, `i` is the element being iterated, *not* the index of the element. Second, returning terminates the function, and therefore the loop. As a result, not only will the script throw you an `IndexError`, but even if you're lucky, it will also return a list with only one element. You can modify it like this:

```
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i)
return list2
```

This would work, except that now we're ignoring the `start` and `end` parameters. (This is why I opted for the `range()` function). If you want to use the Pythonic notation, you would enumerate through the list, check the index, and append if appropriate.

```
for index, element in enumerate(list1):
    if start <= index <= end:
        list2.append(element)
return list2
```